# sql-server and oracle - order by in subselect

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, subquery

I have the following sql, which doesnt work with sql-server, because order by is only allowed in a subselect, when i am using keywords like top.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM ( SELECT pnr, naname, vorname, gebdat, '' p_alter, geschl, gebort
       FROM pgrdat
      WHERE man = 'XYZ'
      ORDER BY pst_ab DESC )
```

Is there any way to get the results i want? The sql should work under oracle too.

I want to distinct on all fields without "pst_ab", but at the same time i want to order it by "pst_ab".

A Workaround would be that i use the order by out of the subselect and the source code make sure that i get all pnr-numbers only once.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables in a relational database are unsorted by nature, and so everything that is used inside a `from` clause is considered as unsorted.
That is the reason SQL Server will not allow you to use an `order by` clause in a derived table, unless you are also using the `top` keyword.

Now, I understand your predicament is this: On one hand, you want distinct values that doesn't include the `pst_ab` column, but on the other hand, you want the values to be ordered by that same column.

Fortunately, you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function for this:

```
SELECT  pnr, 
        naname, 
        vorname, 
        gebdat, 
        p_alter, 
        geschl, 
        gebort
FROM (
    SELECT  pnr, 
            naname, 
            vorname, 
            gebdat, 
            '' p_alter, 
            geschl, 
            gebort, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  pnr, 
                                            naname, 
                                            vorname, 
                                            gebdat, 
                                            geschl, 
                                            gebort 
                                ORDER BY pst_ab DESC) RowNumber
    FROM pgrdat
    WHERE man = 'XYZ'
) d
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

The `ROW_NUMBER` will sort the results by pst_ab and the `WHERE` clause in the outer query will provide the `DISTINCT` functionality.

Tested on Sql server, I think it should work the same on oracle, but I don't have any way of testing that.

Comment: i will try that, thanks a lot - my description should be better next time

Comment: ive tried it on oracle with an other example, it works there too - tomorrow i can test the final result on the productive system, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your distinct and order by;

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        pnr
        ,naname
        ,vorname
        ,gebdat
        ,'' p_alter
        ,geschl
        ,gebort
        ,pst_ab
    FROM pgrdat
    WHERE man = 'XYZ'
    )
ORDER BY pst_ab DESC
```

That way you're still getting the distinct list and it's ordered correctly. Of course, you'll have to include the field pst_ab in your inner select. If you don't want this in the results then try this;

```
SELECT DISTINCT
pnr
,naname
,vorname
,gebdat
,p_alter
,geschl
,gebort
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        pnr
        ,naname
        ,vorname
        ,gebdat
        ,'' p_alter
        ,geschl
        ,gebort
        ,pst_ab
    FROM pgrdat
    WHERE man = 'XYZ'
    )
ORDER BY pst_ab DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull *ORDER BY* out of subselect.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM (SELECT pnr, naname, vorname, gebdat, '' p_alter, geschl, gebort, pst_ab
       FROM pgrdat
      WHERE man = 'XYZ')
ORDER BY pst_ab DESC
```

Comment: With this way i would get every possible combination from all fields ordered by pst_ab. Thats not what i want. Without selecting the "pst_ab" field in the subselect i would get only the "current one" or?

Comment: You can add another column before *pst_ab*, if you are meaning that you have more then one subquery to order.